# giving precedence to arithmetic operators in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I am implementing a simple arithmetic calculation on a server which includes add, sub, mul and Div, for the simplicity purposes no other operations are being done and also no parentheses "()" to change the precedence. The input I will have for the client is something like "1-2.1+3.6*5+10/2"(no dot product, 2.1 or 3.6 is a floating number). I have created a function to send the operands and operators but at a time I can send udp message of 1 computation in the format of (num1,op,num2)

```
import struct
import socket
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 11200
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0) #creating socket
print("Do Ctrl+c to exit the program !!")

def sendRecv( num1, op, num2):
  #sending udp message with num1,op and num
  #receiving udp message with the result as res
  res = s.recieve()
  return res

sendRecv(in1, in_op, in2)
```

I was able to split the operators and operands using the regular split and separated them like

str = ['1', '-', '2.1', '+', '3.6', '*', '5', '+', '10', '/', '2']

since the multiplication and the division takes precedence over addition and subtraction (3.6, *, 5) should be sent first followed by the division, I am trying to write a while loop with while(len(str>0)), I am trying to understand how I can send multiplication first, store the intermediate result in the list itself and do a recurring function till all the computations are sent through message. I am not allowed to perform ny operation on client side, I can only send values to "SendRecv()". Any suggestions or ideas on how to proceed will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you simplify the problem by just having the client send the string and having the server do all the computation?  Having the client try to figure out how to split it up and do the operations in the right order when the client isn't allowed to actually do any computation seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Samwise thanks for the quick response, that is one of the requirements, I am not allowed modify the server, I need to split the sting in client and send them as messages to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for different ideas, I have done my own implementation and tried to keep it very simple. I am not sure if the performance implication is bad on this one, please let me know :-)

```
def calc_buf(arr, operator):
    i = 0    
    while (len(arr) > i):
        if (arr[i] == operator):
            calc = sendRecv(arr[i - 1], arr[i], arr[i + 1])
            global arth_result
            arth_result=calc
            arr[i - 1] = calc
            del arr[i]
            del arr[i]
            break
        i += 1    
        
    return arr
arr =['1', '-', '2.1', '+', '3.6', '*', '5', '+', '10', '/', '2']

    i = 0
    while (count > i):
        i = i + 1
        if '/' in arr:
            calc_buf(arr, '/')
        elif "*" in arr:
            calc_buf(arr, '*')
        elif "-" in arr:
            calc_buf(arr, '-')
        elif "+" in arr:
            calc_buf(arr, '+')        
    #print("actual evaluation:",eval(arth)) #for comparing the computation from server
    print("result=", arth_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursively split the expression according to operator precedence:

```
def do_calc(num1, op, num2):
    # Stub to represent the server call that performs one operation.
    # Note that actually using eval() in your backend is REALLY BAD.
    expr = f"{num1} {op} {num2}" 
    res = str(eval(expr))
    print(expr, "=", res)
    return res

def calc_loop(tokens):
    if len(tokens) == 1:
        return tokens[0]
    if len(tokens) == 3:
        return do_calc(*tokens)
    for ops in "-+", "/*":
        if any(op in tokens for op in ops):
            op_idx = max(tokens.index(op) for op in ops if op in tokens)
            return calc_loop([
                calc_loop(tokens[:op_idx]),
                tokens[op_idx],
                calc_loop(tokens[op_idx+1:]),
            ])

expr = ['1', '-', '2.1', '+', '3.6', '*', '5', '+', '10', '/', '2']
print(' '.join(expr), '=', calc_loop(expr))
```

prints:

```
1 - 2.1 = -1.1
3.6 * 5 = 18.0
10 / 2 = 5.0
18.0 + 5.0 = 23.0
-1.1 + 23.0 = 21.9
1 - 2.1 + 3.6 * 5 + 10 / 2 = 21.9
```

Comment: I think, this code gives an error, after the multiplication and division are done, the order of operations are happening from right to left instead of left to right, for example if there is "1-30-10", the next step its being "1-20" and then being -19 eventually instead of the actual answer being -39,I compared the values with eval, i found a work around by updating the expression like whenever there's a "- 20 -10",I am pushing the "-" into the operand and making it "+(-20) + (-10)), This was solving the issue, but I was wondering if I don't have to do the extra step and modify the existing one

Answer (score 1):

Arrange to process only specific operands in a given pass. Make multiple passes, each with different sets of operators. Splice in the answers as they happen.

```
def doWork(lst, ops):
    lst = list(lst)
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(lst):
        if lst[i] in ops:
            lst[idx-1:idx+2] = sendRecv(*lst[idx-1:idx+2])
        else:
            idx += 1
    return lst

results = doWork(str, '*/')
results = doWork(results, '+-')
results = results[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

A typical use case for the classic [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) :

```
# operators and their precedences
ops = { '*': 2, '/': 2, '+': 1, '-': 1,}

# evaluate a stream of tokens
def evaluate(tokens):
    vstack = []
    ostack = []

    def step():
        v2 = vstack.pop()
        v1 = vstack.pop()
        op = ostack.pop()
        vstack.append(sendRecv(v1, op, v2))

    for tok in tokens:
        if tok in ops:
            if ostack and ops[ostack[-1]] >= ops[tok]:
                step()
            ostack.append(tok)
        else:
            vstack.append(tok)

    while ostack:
        step()

    return vstack.pop()

# simulate the conversation with the server
def sendRecv(v1, op, v2):
    res = eval(f'{v1} {op} {v2}')
    return res

s = '3 + 4 * 2 + 3 / 5 + 6'

print(eval(s))
print(evaluate(s.split()))
```